# Media wiki randomly cannot access the database

Tags: mediawiki

I have media wiki running on a VPS with 256mb ram. From time to time I get the follow page

```
Sorry! This site is experiencing technical difficulties.

Try waiting a few minutes and reloading.

(Cannot access the database: Connection refused (localhost))
```

Would this be because of low ram? I turned on php error reporting in .htaccess but dont get any further info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded my ram from 256 to 768 on the VPS and do not have the error anymore.